# Using values as a validation check in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a script which takes zip files apart and counts how many files are in that zip. For validation check, I need to use the `INT` that function puts out and do an if statement with it, how can I get this to work?

```
$zipFile = $request->file('fupload');
    $templatename = $request->input('template_name');
    $file_to_open = $request->file('fupload')->getRealPath();
    $target = storage_path();

    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($file_to_open) == TRUE) {

        for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
            $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);

            if ( stristr($filename, '__MACOSX') === FALSE )
            {
                $path_parts = pathinfo($filename);

                if ( isset($path_parts['extension']) && !isset( $this->extensions[$path_parts['extension']] ) )
                {
                    $this->extensions[$path_parts['extension']] = 1;
                } else if ( isset($path_parts['extension']) )
                {
                    $this->extensions[$path_parts['extension']] = $this->extensions[$path_parts['extension']] + 1;
                }

                if ( isset($path_parts['extension']) && ($path_parts['extension'] == 'html' || $path_parts['extension'] == 'htm' ) )
                {
                    $this->html = $zip->getFromName($filename);
                    $this->files[] = (object) [ 'filename' => basename($filename), 'contents' => $zip->getFromName($filename)];
                } else if ( isset($path_parts['extension']) ) {
                    $this->files[] = (object) [ 'filename' => basename($filename), 'contents' => $zip->getFromName($filename)];
                }
            }
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($templatename, $this->extensions);
        $this->validateZipfiles();

    }
    unlink($file_to_open);
}
```

Comment: Your question `need to use the INT that function puts out and do an if statement with it, how can I get this to work?` is not very clear to me, can you please rephrase it?

Comment: For every file extension the zip file contains its going to start counting so for example: There are three .html files in the zip file, 1 .css and 2 .jpg. It is gonna create an array that says "array(3) {
  ["css"]=>
  int(1)
  ["html"]=>
  int(3)
  ["jpg"]=>
  int(2)
}"

Comment: My question here is how can I take these ints and make something like if $this->[$path_parts['html]] == 1 { do this .... }

Comment: Are you still here Thomas?

Comment: Yes, but I made 1 attemp to clarify I don't exactly understand your question and you answer with an even harder to understand explaination. Please try https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask